# change iframe height while the child is from onother domain

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe, cross-domain

I am using Facebook apps, and Facebook apps requires to put your application in an iFrame,
everything is going fine except than that the height if the iframe the create is static and i want to change the height of the iFrame,
i tried the following :

```
jQuery(parent.document.body.getElementsByTagName('iframe')).load(function() {
  this.style.height =
  this.contentWindow.document.body.offsetHeight + 'px';
});
```

but when trying to access the parent document

```
parent.document
```

an error occurs

```
Unsafe JavaScript attempt to access frame with URL  
http://www.facebook.com/somthing/app_100550322222338 from frame with URL 
http://z.me/facebook/whatsnew. Domains, protocols and ports must match.
```

is there any other solutions ??

Answer (score 0):

There is no client script solution, as the page and the iframe comes from different domains.

If you set up a proxy page on your server that fetches the facebook page, they would appear to the browser to come from the same domain, so then the script would work.